# Can shop-bought caustic soda be used to measure titratable acidity of wines?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, home-experiment, titration

When making wines, it's occasionally necessary to measure the wine's 'titratable acidity' (TA). To do this, a 0.1N solution of NaOH is titrated with a wine sample. 0.1N NaOH solution can be purchased, but I'd like to know if I can make it myself using household caustic soda.

I want to make 100ml of 0.1N NaOH solution, which I understand involves adding 0.4g of NaOH to 100ml of water.

I have household caustic soda (as used for cleaning drains), but I have no idea whether this is pure NaOH. It only needs to be 'pure enough' for the purposes of getting an accurate TA reading from my wines.

How would I determine whether the caustic soda I have in my cupboard is pure enough for the purposes of measuring TA? I have a pH meter, and I know that 0.1N NaOH should be pH 13; does this mean that so long as the resulting solution is pH 13 then the solution is suitable for measuring TA?

(*Note: in order to measure TA, I would take a 15ml sample of wine, and keep adding 0.1N NaOH until the pH = 8.2 The TA would be the amount of NaOH added (in ml) divided by two. A typical TA is 6-9 g/l.*)

Comment: In our quantitative analysis course, students carefully prepared sodium hydroxide solutions from reagent grade solid sodium hydroxide. This requires care and following a valid preparation protocol: it is easy to mess up. Then they standardize their sodium hydroxide solutions against a primary standard acid, typically potassium hydrogen phthalate (KHP). Only then are their sodium hydroxide solutions acceptable for use in the titration of acids in samples.

Comment: Commercial caustic soda is usually pure enough for making up  $0.1 M \ce{NaOH}$ solution. But don't try to measure the $p$H of the obtained solution. A $0.1 M \ce{NaOH }$ solution does not have a $p$H exactly equal to  $13.00$, because of the activity effect. The relation $p\ce{H} = - log[\ce{H^+}]$ is only valid at concentration $\ce{[H^+] < 0.01} M$. At higher concentrations, the concentration should be replaced by the activity.

Comment: I do not see how this could be a personal medical question.// As [Homework](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) is considered literal homework, exams, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.

Comment: Homework is often selected as a reason to close by people who feel a question could be answered with minimal research by the OP. In essence your question is covered in introductory analytical chemistry courses, within the topic of acid/base standardization, and a typical textbook will cover the topic satisfactorily.

Comment: @BuckThorn I think the question is rather specific, bypassing general topic of acidobasic volumetry, covered by textbooks. It is rather for out of lab context of cheap, available chemicals, questioning being pure enough to make orientation/screening quality titration with acceptable accuracy.